# selenium, getting links from an array

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()

 for element in links:
    driver.get(element)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    #driver.switchTo().window()
    driver.close()
    date = soup.find_all("td", {"id": "utime"})
    title = soup("title")
```

The link is list of the urls, which I need to parse. First element of the link is okey but when second link opens;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/Version01.py", line 10, in <module>
driver.get(element)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver     /remote/webdriver.py", line 199, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver /remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
  return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
 .......
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 778, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in   create_connection
raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

How can I browse different links from an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You close your `driver` inside the for-loop, thus the second iteration can not work with it anymore.

Try using `driver.close()` after the for-loop:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

for element in links:
    driver.do_something()

driver.close()
```